# Access appCatalog of sharepoint 2013 preview site through rest

Tags: sharepoint, rest, sharepoint-2013

I need to get application information from a SharePoint 2013 site through the rest interface. Normally it can be done with client object model by using `AppCatalog.GetAppInstances()` . method. Problem occurs when you try to get same information via rest endpoint. 
For example execution of https://.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.AppCatalog.GetAppInstances
returns

```
> <m:error><m:code>-1,
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException</m:code><m:message
> xml:lang="en-US">The method GetAppInstances cannot be invoked as its
> parameter web is not supported.</m:message></m:error>
```

Does it mean this method cannot be run via rest or am I missing something? Or would be great if someone knows an alternative to access same info..

Comment: Did you ever found out solution for this?